# How do I know I should turn swappiness down?

Tags: linux, swap

I have 5.5 GiB memory, using 2.8 GiB (~50%), but my swap is using 1.9 GiB of 5.6 GiB (~33%). My computer operates okay but is sluggish at times.

So is this a high amount of swap usage or completely normal?

```
         TOTAL      USED       %
  MEM    5.5 GiB    2.8 GiB    50%
  SWP    5.6 GiB    1.9 GiB    33%
  -----------------------------------------
  TOTAL  11.1 GiB   4.7 GiB    83%


  Linux base 3.18.3-201.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP 
  Mon Jan 19 15:59:31 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 
  GNU/Linux

  cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
  60  //default
```

ran

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10
```

but nothing happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not important how much swap is ussed unless it is full. It is more important how much swap in swap out operations per second you have. Swapin/swapout can be monitored with `vmstat`, `sar` or `dstat`.

If swap is full and swapin/swapout operations are very low, you can just add more swap.